# Kendo UI Controls Are Not Working Properly With FireFox

Tags: firefox, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown, kendo-datepicker

I am using Kendo UI controls in my application. And recently I found one big issue of Kendo controls while working on FireFox.

I found that some of the Kendo UI controls are not working properly in firefox.

Like :- KendoDatePicker, Kendo().Dropdownlist().

1) KendoDatePicker() :-

When I use $("#DatePicker").KendoDatePicker() then the KendoDatePicker calendar is not showing in firefox.

I found that firefox is not taking Kendo.default.min.css . But when I checked similar functionality with IE or Chrome then it was working. And taking the above CSS.

2) Html.Kendo().DropDownList() :-

If i change the Dropdownlist item with Mouse than its not replacing the item in firefox.
But working well in other browsers.

Below is the piece of code of Dropdownlist :-

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("SelectedCategory")  
.DataTextField("Text")
.DataValueField("Text")
.Value(Model)       
.BindTo(ViewBag.Categories)    
)
```

> > Can anyone help me out on this ? Is there any default issue with Kendo UI Controls and FireFox ?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the javascript console on firefox?

Answer (score 5):

The Kendo UI Team has identified a problem with the Popup in Firefox, which affects all Kendo UI Widgets that use it. The issue only manifests itself when the page is scrolled as inability to open the Popup there.

There is an easy alternative fix with CSS only. Force your desired overflow on the document element, like this:

```
 .k-ff { overflow: inherit !important;}
```

The selector above will affect only Firefox. Adjust the overflow to your needs (visible, auto, hidden, scroll, inherit).

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this problem in Mozila Firefox and since today and in Google Chrome version 61.....

After a lot of head banging I found out a solution!

It turned out that each Kendo UI release has Supported jQuery Versions. They could be found here - http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#jquery.

In my case I have Kendo UI 2016.3.1118 (R3 2016 SP2) and I used jQuery 2.2.3, which caused my problem. I switched it as per the above linked documentation to 1.12.3 and my DropDownList problems disappered.

I hope will save a lot efforts to many of you, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for that.As i mentioned the Kendo controls are not working only in firefox and working in other browsers.So i just checked by re installing the Firefox and now all Kendo controls working properly in Firefox.